# Is it impossible to scrape this website using Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape Hate Symbol information (the name, symbol type, description, ideology, location, and images) from the [GPAHE website](https://globalextremism.org/global-extremist-symbols-database/) using Selenium. One of the first steps I try is to set input_element to the XPATH of Symbol type. My problem is I keep getting a NoSuchElementException with my code for input_element. I have quadruple checked that the XPATH correctly references the Symbol type and exists on the page.

I have tried everything I can think of: implementing WebDriverWait up to 20 seconds, scrolling down the page, modifying the path in one way or another, etc.

I then decided to just take out the input_element portion of the code and forget about extracting Symbol type. So my code is supposed to keep clicking the 'Load More' button at the bottom of the page until it is no longer present on the page (see try-except block), but even that doesn't seem to work for me and gives me a similar error. Is it just possible that the website is impossible to scrape using Selenium?

Here is the error message:

```
Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div/section/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/input"}
  (Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.71); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6536E4D02+56194]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6536504B2]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6534F76AA]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6535416D0]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6535417EC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF653584D77]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF653565EBF]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF653582786]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF653565C23]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF653534A45]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF653535AD4]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF653A5D5BB+3695675]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF653AB6197+4059159]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF653AADF63+4025827]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF65377F029+687785]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65365B508]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF653657564]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6536576E9]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF653648094]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFF7A4C257D+29]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFF7B2CAA58+40]
  File "\\WSL.LOCALHOST\UBUNTU\home\user\scraper\items\hatesymbols\names_hatesymbols_gpahe.py", line 34, in <module>
    input_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/section/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/input")
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div/section/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/input"}
  (Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.71); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6536E4D02+56194]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6536504B2]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6534F76AA]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6535416D0]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6535417EC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF653584D77]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF653565EBF]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF653582786]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF653565C23]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF653534A45]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF653535AD4]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF653A5D5BB+3695675]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF653AB6197+4059159]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF653AADF63+4025827]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF65377F029+687785]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65365B508]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF653657564]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6536576E9]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF653648094]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFF7A4C257D+29]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFF7B2CAA58+40]
```

Here is my code below:

````
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
import json

def parse_profile(hatesymbol_url):
    image_list = []
    try:
        driver.get(hatesymbol_url) #opens hate symbol's profile page
        time.sleep(4)
        
        images = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='css-1l7c0cy']")
        for image in images:
            image_url = image.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//img[@class='MuiCardMedia-root MuiCardMedia-media MuiCardMedia-img paper css-rhsghg']").get_attribute("src")
            image_list.append(image_url)
    except (StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchElementException):
        print("An error occurred on {}.".format(hatesymbol_url))
    return image_list

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
gpahe_url = "https://globalextremism.org/global-extremist-symbols-database/"
driver.get(gpahe_url)
driver.maximize_window()
symbol_types = ['Hand Sign', 'Hate Image', 'Hateful Clothing', 'Hateful Literature', 'Hateful Media', 'Hateful Music', "Text"]

# Scroll down the page in increments until all images are visible
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight * 0.1);")
time.sleep(1)
input_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/section/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/input")

all_symbols = []

for symbol_type in symbol_types:
    input_element.send_keys(symbol_type)

    while True: 
        try:
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//button[@class='MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-containedSizeMedium css-193ezh']").click()
            time.sleep(2)
        except:
            print('No more elements')
            break

    elems = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='horizontal-list-item MuiBox-root css-zdcb3j']")

    for elem in elems:
        symbol = {}
        symbol['name'] = elem.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//h2[@class='sw-width-l sw-font-size-2xl sw-text-color-0A0A0A sw-font-family-default sw-font-weight-semibold sw-text-align-left sw-letter-spacing-wider sw-padding-top-none sw-padding-bottom-none sw-padding-left-none sw-padding-right-none MuiBox-root css-vi1jz3']").text.strip()
        symbol['metadata'] = {}
        symbol['metadata']['url'] = elem.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a[@class='MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-containedSizeMedium MuiBox-root css-n8dvpa']").get_attribute("href")
        symbol['metadata']['type'] = symbol_type

        symbol['metadata']['ideology'] = []
        ideo_elems = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='css-zq5ip9']//span[@class='MuiChip-label MuiChip-labelMedium css-1cjkvaf']")
        for ideo_elem in ideo_elems:
            ideo = ideo_elem.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span").text
            symbol['metadata']['ideology'].append(ideo)

        symbol['metadata']['location'] = []
        loc_elems = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='css-yv67l3']//span[@class='MuiChip-label MuiChip-labelMedium css-1cjkvaf']")
        for loc_elem in loc_elems:
            loc = loc_elem.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span").text
            symbol['metadata']['location'].append(loc) 
        
        symbol['metadata']['description'] = elem.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='sw-width-s sw-font-size-m sw-text-color-0A0A0A sw-font-family-default sw-font-weight-light sw-text-align-left sw-letter-spacing-normal sw-padding-top-7xs sw-padding-bottom-none sw-padding-left-none sw-padding-right-6xs rich-text MuiBox-root css-11b53ld']").text.strip()

        all_symbols.append(symbol)

for symbol in all_symbols:
    symbol_images = parse_profile(symbol['metadata']['url']) 
    symbol['official_image'] = symbol_images```
````

Comment: If the site is accessible via a human using a web browser, then it should be scrapeable via selenium.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: sometimes servers may send different HTML for different users, different browsers, or different devices, and for browsers which don't run JavaScript. Servers may also detect `Selenium` and send warning or Captcha. Other problem is when it display in `<iframe>` because Selenium treads it as different page and you need `switch_to.frame`. Page may also use `shadow DOM` and code may not see it.

Comment: Selenium may not access element if it is not visible in window - and it needs to scroll it. It may also has problem if element is behind other elements - ie. `popup` about `cookies` - and it needs to close it (or remove it using JavaScript). So script has to behave like real human :)

Comment: Thanks. I've added the full error message. It doesn't appear to be sending a warning or a captcha, but it does seem like the issue may be with iframes.

Answer (score 4):

I checked page and it has few `<iframe>` and one of them has `<input>` so first you have to find this `<iframe>` and use `switch_to.frame()`

This `iframe` has long `id` like this

```
frame = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="softr-2c9b18da-3f19-4944-ae4d-64a5ee3b56a4-list2"]')

driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

But I'm afraid it may change this ID in the future or for different uses.

But `<input>` is in first `<iframe>` and this also works for me

```
frame = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//iframe')

driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

And later I needed

```
input_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id=":r0:"]')
```

or

```
input_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@placeholder="Type here to search"]')
```

I saw it puts text in this `<input>` and it display results.

But it has problem with rest of code. Maybe it needs to switch to another `<iframe>` or switch back to `main window` (using something  like `driver.switch_to.window(...)`)

And probably it will need to switch again to first `<iframe>` to put next text in `<input>` - so this code may need to be in `for`-loop with rest of code.

---

I see another problem in code. You use `.click()` - and if this will load new page then you will have to go back to previous page and search again `<iframe>` and `<input>` because when browser load new page then it removes from memory information about previous page and it doesn't have acccess to `<iframe>` and `<input>` (even if you  load again the same page)